# how to add 2 differentfigures in mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created 2 different figures(Fig1 and Fig2) in mathplotlib and saved them in pdf. Can anybody help me how to merger these 2 figures and create single figure. fig1 and fig2 has same x-Axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

def lc_fslg(target,position,axes,titel,exc_true,l_pos):

    for axi in axes:
        pp = PdfPages('output\ ' + 'lc_over_fuselage_'+ axi + '.pdf')
        plt.figure()
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.text(0.5, 0.5, titel+str(axi), ha='center', va='center')
        pp.savefig()
        plt.close()
        for kind in ['ground','flight']:
            plot_load_flow(target, position, kind, axi.lower(), titel, exc_true, l_pos)
            plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf', papertype='a4', orientation='landscape', bbox_inches='tight')
            plt.close('all')
        pp.close()


def plot_load_flow(target,position,kind,axe,titel,exc_true,l_pos):

    d_ax_label = {'tx': 'Tx [daN]', 'ty': 'Ty [daN]', 'tz': 'Tz [daN]'
        , 'mx': 'Mx [daNm]', 'my': 'My [daNm]', 'mz': 'Mz [daNm]'}

    max_v=[]
    min_v=[]
    max_vM=[]
    min_vM=[]
    pos_env=[]
    if(kind == 'ground'):
        for pos in l_pos:
            load_at_pos = target.uload_at(pos)
            max = load_at_pos[axe].loc[(load_at_pos['position'] == pos) & (load_at_pos['type'] == 'X')].max()
            min = load_at_pos[axe].loc[(load_at_pos['position'] == pos) & (load_at_pos['type'] == 'X')].min()
            if(not(np.isnan(max))& (not(np.isnan(min)))):
                max_v.append(max)
                min_v.append(min)
                pos_env.append(pos)
        x_env = [position[pos] for pos in pos_env]
        plt.clf()
        fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
        plt.plot(x_env, max_v, 'b-', markersize=15,linewidth=3.5, label='envelope '+str(kind))
        plt.plot(x_env, min_v, 'b-', markersize=15,linewidth=3.5)



    if(kind == 'flight'):
        for pos in l_pos:
            load_at_pos = target.uload_at(pos)
            max = load_at_pos[axe].loc[(load_at_pos['position'] == pos)
                                    & ((load_at_pos['type'] == 'G') | (load_at_pos['type'] == 'M'))].max()
            min = load_at_pos[axe].loc[(load_at_pos['position'] == pos)
                                    & ((load_at_pos['type'] == 'G') | (load_at_pos['type'] == 'M'))].min()
            if (not (np.isnan(max)) & (not (np.isnan(min)))):
                max_vM.append(max)
                min_vM.append(min)
                pos_env.append(pos)
        x_env = [position[pos] for pos in pos_env]
        plt.clf()
        fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
        plt.plot(x_env, max_v, 'b-', markersize=15,linewidth=3.5, label='envelope '+str(kind))
        plt.plot(x_env, min_v, 'b-', markersize=15,linewidth=3.5)
        plt.plot(x_env, max_vM, 'g-', markersize=15,linewidth=3.5, label='envelope '+str(kind))
        plt.plot(x_env, min_vM, 'g-', markersize=15,linewidth=3.5)
    # define plot layout
    plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.ylabel(d_ax_label[axe], fontsize=30)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
    plt.xticks(x_env,pos_env,fontsize=20,rotation='vertical')
    plt.xlabel('frame position', fontsize=30)
    plt.title(titel, fontsize=20)
    legend = plt.legend(shadow=True, prop={'size': 20})
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: you can plot multiple lines and only save the figure afterward.

Comment: You can in general not merge figures. Are you looking for a way to create a single pdf of the two figures?

Comment: `plt.subplots`?  `plt.subplot`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am experienced aerospace engineer but never programmed.until now i was using only excel files to plot or read data but I realised that python is strong tool to visualise data. So can you please help me further. I have a some data in text files and it has 2 different data( for example a and b). I want ot create a graph with data 'a' as one line and data'b' as one line. This is the reason there is if condition!